# Why is my network unreachable in virtual machine with RHEL 7.2?

Tags: networking, rhel

I got a 30-Day evaluation of RHEL 7.2.

I installed into a VirtualBox machine, and tried to register my subscription:

```
# subscription-manager register
Registering to: subscription.rhn.redhat.com:443/subscription
Username: ***
Password: 
Network error, unable to connect to server. Please see /var/log/rhsm/rhsm.log for more information.
```

The log said there was a network error:

```
2016-06-10 17:35:13,853 [INFO] subscription-manager:2398 @connection.py:778 - Connection built: host=subscription.rhn.redhat.com port=443 handler=/subscription auth=basic username=***
2016-06-10 17:35:13,899 [DEBUG] subscription-manager:2398 @hwprobe.py:554 - cpu info: {'cpu.cpu(s)': 1, 'cpu.core(s)_per_socket': 1, 'cpu.thread(s)_per_core': 1, 'cpu.topology_source': 'kernel /sys cpu sibling lists', 'cpu.cpu_socket(s)': 1}
2016-06-10 17:36:34,000 [DEBUG] subscription-manager:2398 @hwprobe.py:772 - Running 'virt-what'
2016-06-10 17:36:34,059 [DEBUG] subscription-manager:2398 @hwprobe.py:776 - virt-what stdout: virtualbox
kvm

2016-06-10 17:36:34,059 [DEBUG] subscription-manager:2398 @hwprobe.py:777 - virt-what stderr: 
2016-06-10 17:36:34,068 [INFO] subscription-manager:2398 @hwprobe.py:854 - collected virt facts: virt.is_guest=True, virt.host_type=virtualbox, kvm, virt.uuid=bcb0c5f9-560d-44df-b8b7-3a085d08cff5
2016-06-10 17:36:34,069 [DEBUG] subscription-manager:2398 @connection.py:475 - Loaded CA certificates from /etc/rhsm/ca/: redhat-uep.pem
2016-06-10 17:36:34,069 [DEBUG] subscription-manager:2398 @connection.py:523 - Making request: GET /subscription/users/***/owners
2016-06-10 17:37:14,122 [ERROR] subscription-manager:2398 @managercli.py:160 - Error during registration: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
2016-06-10 17:37:14,123 [ERROR] subscription-manager:2398 @managercli.py:161 - [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

However it seems to be more than just DNS.
I am using a bridged adapter: [image: screenshot]
I have connected through ssh.
The router is 192.168.0.1, the host is 192.168.0.103 and the guest is 192.168.0.100.
I can ping the host from the guest:

```
# ping -c 1 192.168.0.103
PING 192.168.0.103 (192.168.0.103) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.103: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.342 ms

--- 192.168.0.103 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.342/0.342/0.342/0.000 ms
```

But I can't ping the router. Or anything else beyond that.

```
# ping -c 1 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

The output of `ip route`:

```
# ip route
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.100  metric 100
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has the guest's default route been set up properly?  Add the result of `ip route` to your question.

Comment: Added `ip route` output.

Comment: What type of NIC does the host have? There are sometimes issues using bridged networking with a WiFi NIC.

Comment: The host has a WiFi NIC. But I used a bridged adapter for many virtual machines on this host, and never had any problems.

Comment: Good point though, Mark! I switched to a NAT adapter, and now the network works fine.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that there isn't another `192.168.0.100` on the network? Maybe allocated by the router's DHCP, so you're not necessarily aware of it (other people's smartphones etc).

Comment: @garethTheRed, you're right! My router had an ARP binding for `192.168.0.100` and a MAC address that didn't belong to the virtual machine. Strange that it was still used by DHCP. I solved this by making a DHCP address reservation. I assigned a new IP (`192.168.0.125`) to the MAC addrerss of the virtual machine. Now it works perfectly with a bridged adapter.

Comment: you just could have used NAT rather than bridge